# Bootstrap Navbar Not Collapsing for Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I am working on a website, heres a draft: http://46.101.21.230/ and I've used bootstrap before and not had this issue. When the page is in mobile view, the navbar does not collapse, it just goes into the normal bar.

I have jQuery and bootstrap.js loaded and the language selector dropdown at the top works fine so I'm guessing that's not the problem.

I went onto the bootstrap website and got the example code and pasted that in too and it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is what I see: https://imgur.com/h7Kd8dy

Is this wrong?

Comment: Btw, your "lfa.js" contains errors. TypeError: $('.dropdown-select').btComboBox(); is not a function.

Comment: I have removed any JS that might cause it not to work and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. I am using SASS and didn't include component animations. In future use this

@import "bootstrap/component-animations";